# Stubbing a method called by a class' constructor

Tags: php, phpunit

How does one stub a method in PHPUnit that is called by the class under test's constructor? The simple code below for example won't work because by the time I declare the stubbed method, the stub object has already been created and my method called, unstubbed.

Class to test:

```
class ClassA {
  private $dog;
  private $formatted;

  public function __construct($param1) { 
     $this->dog = $param1;       
     $this->getResultFromRemoteServer();
  }

  // Would normally be private, made public for stubbing
  public getResultFromRemoteServer() {
    $this->formatted = file_get_contents('http://whatever.com/index.php?'.$this->dog);
  }

  public getFormatted() {
    return ("The dog is a ".$this->formatted);
  }
}
```

Test code:

```
class ClassATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testPoodle() {  
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')
                 ->setMethods(array('getResultFromRemoteServer'))
                 ->setConstructorArgs(array('dog52'))
                 ->getMock();

    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('getResultFromRemoteServer')
         ->will($this->returnValue('Poodle'));

    $expected = 'This dog is a Poodle';
    $actual = $stub->getFormatted();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not the stubbing of the method, but your class.

You are doing work in the constructor. In order to set the object into state, you fetch a remote file. But that step is not necessary, because the object doesn't need that data to be in a valid state. You dont need the result from the file before you actually call `getFormatted`.

You could defer loading:

```
class ClassA {
  private $dog;
  private $formatted;

  public function __construct($param1) { 
     $this->dog = $param1;       
  }
  protected getResultFromRemoteServer() {
    if (!$this->formatted) {
        $this->formatted = file_get_contents(
            'http://whatever.com/index.php?' . $this->dog
        );
    }
    return $this->formatted;
  }
  public getFormatted() {
    return ("The dog is a " . $this->getResultFromRemoteServer());
  }
}
```

so you are lazy loading the remote access to when it's actually needed. Now you dont need to stub `getResultFromRemoteServer` at all, but can stub `getFormatted` instead. You also won't need to open your API for the testing and make `getResultFromRemoteServer` public then.

On a sidenote, even if it's just an example, I would rewrite that class to read

```
class DogFinder
{
    protected $lookupUri;
    protected $cache = array();
    public function __construct($lookupUri)
    {
        $this->lookupUri = $lookupUri;
    }
    protected function findById($dog)
    {
        if (!isset($this->cache[$dog])) {
            $this->cache[$dog] = file_get_contents(
                urlencode($this->lookupUri . $dog)
            );
        }
        return $this->cache[$id];
    }
    public function getFormatted($dog, $format = 'This is a %s')
    {
        return sprintf($format, $this->findById($dog));
    }
}
```

Since it's a Finder, it might make more sense to actually have `findById` public now. Just keeping it protected because that's what you had in your example.

---

**The other option** would be to extend the *Subject-Under-Test* and replace the method `getResultFromRemoteServer` with your own implementation returning `Poodle`. This would mean you are not testing the actual `ClassA`, but a subclass of `ClassA`, but this is what happens when you use the Mock API anyway.

As of PHP7, you could utilize an Anonymous class like this:

```
public function testPoodle() {

    $stub = new class('dog52') extends ClassA {
      public function getResultFromRemoteServer() {
          return 'Poodle';
      }
    };

    $expected = 'This dog is a Poodle';
    $actual = $stub->getFormatted();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

Before PHP7, you'd just write a regular class extending the *Subject-Under-Test* and use that instead of the *Subject-Under-Test*. Or use `disableOriginalConstructor` as shown elsewhere on this page.

Comment: I'm hearing you and I agree. The code above I just whipped up for the ease of illustration, but it reflects the code I'm working on. <continued on next comment, I keep on pressing Enter>

Comment: I'll see how popping the remote call later fits in to the real code. It was just one of those situations where I didn't have a class originally because it wasn't needed, but added it because of ease of testing and mocking.

Comment: @stebbo feel free to drop by the chat if you have any additional questions.

Comment: This is NOT an answer to the original question AT ALL. "You should be doing Y instead and then you won't need to do X" is NOT an answer to "How do I do X?".

Comment: @Szczepan true, but that is irrelevant because the alternative shown is cleaner and solved the OPs problem.

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski Since I assume you were coming to this question learning "how to do X", I've updated the answer to include "how to do X".

Answer (score 52):

Use `disableOriginalConstructor()` so that `getMock()` won't call the constructor. The name is a bit misleading because calling that method ends up passing `false` for `$callOriginalConstructor`. This allows you to set expectations on the returned mock before calling the constructor manually.

```
$stub = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassA')
             ->setMethods(array('getResultFromRemoteServer'))
             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
             ->getMock();
$stub->expects($this->any())
     ->method('getResultFromRemoteServer')
     ->will($this->returnValue('Poodle'));
$stub->__construct('dog52');
...
```

Comment: That sounds perfect. I'll probably restructure as Gordon suggested but I'll keep it in mind. Thanks again David.

Comment: B-e-a-utiful! This exact issue caused a cascade of errors which I narrowed down to my mocked method not being called from the constructor. This answer solves @jontyc's (and my) question perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: exactly what I'm find.